# Changing the language by clicking on an image does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a project where we will soon be able to change the language of texts by clicking on a flag. If I use selects it works perfectly (translation works).

Functional code

```
<select onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)" >
     <option {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='en'?'selected':''):''}} value="en">English</option>
     <option {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='fr'?'selected':''):''}} value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

But I would like to replace options in select with images (English flag, Spanish flag, etc. .. ) and it doesn't work anymore at the time of the click .. My syntax must not be good.

Nonfunctional code

```
<img onclick="changeLanguage(this.value)" src="{{ asset('images/flags/english.png') }}" alt="" {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='en'?'selected':''):''}}>

<img  onclick="changeLanguage(this.value)" src="{{ asset('images/flags/french.png') }}" alt="" {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='en'?'selected':''):''}}>
```

EDITED
I replace

```
<script>  function changeLanguage(lang){ 
    window.location='{{url("change-language")}}/'+lang; } 
</script>
```

WITH

```
<img data-value="en" onclick="changeLanguage(this.value)" src="{{ asset('images/flags/french.png') }}" alt="" {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='en'?'selected':''):''}}>
```

```
function changeLanguage(this.getAttribute('data-value')){ window.location='{{url("change-language")}}/'+lang; }
```

but I have many syntax errors (, and ; expected)
Any ideas ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Because img tag don't have a value attribute. You should declare a new attribute for img tag and then pass this attribute to your js function. Like `changeLanguage(this.getAttribute("data-value"))`. And your img tag should look like `<img data-value="your_lang_key">`

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, please, hard to read. Instead, [edit] your question and place relevant information there

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question :) @brombeer

Answer (score -1):

You can use img tag in your option's child element

```
<select onchange="changeLanguage(this.value)" >
     <option {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='en'?'selected':''):''}} value="en">
       <img src="{{ asset('images/flags/english.png') }}" />
       English
     </option>
     <option {{session()->has('lang_code')?(session()->get('lang_code')=='fr'?'selected':''):''}} value="fr">
       <img src="{{ asset('images/flags/french.png') }}" />
       French
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I just tried and the select works but the images are not displayed.

Comment: `<option>` elements take _text_ content, no images will be shown